# Loading .matrix file in R

Tags: r

I have a zip folder containing many .matrix files, which need to be loaded into R for seriation. 
Currently I am using read.table for each .matrix file but the out I received is

1010 instead of 1 0 1 0

```
Sample . matrix file : 
==> 01-ki-5x7.gt.matrix <==
0101110
1010000
1010011
0101010
1000101
```

Comment: Without seeing a couple of lines of the files, it's hard to provide any assistance.... Can you post the output of `readLines("yourfile", n = 5)` or something like that so we can get a sense of what you are working with?

Comment: ==> 0,1,-ki-5x7.gt.matrix <==
0,1,0,1,1,1,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,0,1,1
0,1,0,1,0,1,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,1

Comment: Please use the "edit" link under your question and put the text in using proper formatting. It's hard to see what we are dealing with in comments.

Comment: This is one sample .matrix file

Comment: Is it all just a single line? Did you try `scan`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Output using Readlines  '[1] "./._binary_matrices" "0101110"             "1010000"             "1010011"            
[5] "0101010" '

Comment: It doesn't look like there are any separating characters. Read it in an split it up using `strsplit`?

Comment: I wrote the following LOC:                                                                                                            'm1 <-scan('C:/Users/uni pc/Desktop/binary_matrices/01-ki-5x7.gt.matrix')
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(m1, split = "")))'                                                                                                      Output:
Error in strsplit(m1, split = "") : non-character argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have read the data in using `readLines` or `scan` and ended up with something like:

```
x <- c("0101110", "1010000", "1010011", "0101010", "1000101")
```

You can convert it to a `matrix` using something like:

```
> t(sapply(strsplit(x, "", TRUE), as.numeric))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0
[5,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1
```

---

You may also be able to get a little bit more speed out of something like:

```
t(vapply(strsplit(x, "", TRUE), as.numeric, numeric(nchar(x[1]))))
```

---

Alternatively, you can try `read_fwf` from the "readr" package (you can use `read.fwf` in base too, but I've always found it to be very slow). The approach might be something like:

```
library(readr)
read_fwf("yourfile", fwf_widths(rep(1, nchar(readLines("yourfile", n = 1)))))
# Source: local data frame [5 x 7]
# 
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7
# 1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
# 2  1  0  1  0  0  0  0
# 3  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
# 4  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
# 5  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: I am still getting an error 'Error in vapply(strsplit(m2, "", TRUE), as.numeric, numeric(nchar(x[1]))) : 
  values must be length 3,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 6'

Comment: @CK, try `numeric(nchar(m2[1]))` instead.

Comment: @CK, Have you tried the last option I suggested (`read_fwf`)? If you know the number of columns you expect, you can replace the `fwf_widths` part with `fwf_widths(rep(1, howevermanycolumnsyouhave))`.